# How can I get the binary image returned from a php file stored as a variable?

Tags: php, html, image, fpdf, google-maps-static-api

I am creating a PDF with fpdf
I can insert an image such as

```
$pdf->Image('images/image.jpg',0,20,210,80);
```

I can insert an image such as

```
$pdf->Image('http://www.thesearchagents.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Google-Search.jpg',0,20,210,80);
```

in HTML I can serve an image to my page with

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false" alt="image" height="200" width="300" />
```

but if I try

```
$pdf->Image('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false',0,20,210,80);
```

I get an error

```
"FPDF error: Unsupported image type: php"
```

since it is not the actual image file and is only serving the image I am guessing it does not work with setting the header

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

what can I do?

Can I capture the image binary and store it in a variable? to then be passed along?

If so, then my question is:
How do capture the image source from a return of a php file and store it in a variable in php?

Comment: you could probably edit the FPDF function to allow it. its an FPDF error, not a php one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$bin = file_get_contents('http://your_image_binary_source_url_here'); //fetch binary source

$local_name = "/tmp/".time().'.png';
file_put_contents($local_name, $bin); //create image locally

$pdf->Image($local_name,0,20,210,80); //add image to pdf

unlink($local_name); //delete local image
```

Comment: Works great! only thing is FPDF requires a extension type - or a explict type - so also needs the extension in the param list